# Where can I see when a GitHub repository was made public?

Tags: github

Let's consider, for example, the GitHub repository, https://github.com/langchain-ai/auto-evaluator. Where can I see when a  GitHub repository was made public?

---

Notes:

1. I don't have any special access to the  GitHub repository. E.g., I'm not the owner, and I'm not a collaborator.
2. The question isn't related to developing a program.
3. I Googled the question but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: [How to find the "going public" date of a repository project on GitHub? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445643/how-to-find-the-going-public-date-of-a-repository-project-on-github)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, I believe that the answer posted there won't work since I don't have any special access to the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://redd.it/13cis1k, it looks like it is not possible to see when a GitHub repository was made public, unless one has some special access to the GitHub repository.

Quote from Reddit user [Folaefolc](https://www.reddit.com/user/Folaefolc) on https://redd.it/13cis1k:

> You can't, without access to the logs.

and the logs cannot be accessed unless one has some special access to the GitHub repository.